# Why does not work changing UIButton text via dot syntax?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, title

Is it possible to change UIButton title label text via dot syntax? The text is not changing if I do it via dot syntax:

```
self.myButton.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:@"Nop"];
```

But this one does:

```
[self.myButton setTitle: @"Yep" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Text change works for pure UILabels, is UIButton a special case or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because the text can be changed for a UIButton for several different states (Normal, Highlighted, etc). Apple simply chose to require explicit code to set the text. You could probably create a category to implement this, if you really wanted.

Comment: Hm, maybe there is some logic in that :) As with categories I'm not in comfort using them because IMHO it just makes code harder to read later or even for other person. For example, if you are building some large app then you are having a lot different class files, helpers and etc. If you put some methods in categories then you need to have a clear file naming conventions in order to find "hidden&custom" functionality. It just my opinion, what is yours on that?

Comment: Honestly, I'm fine with creating categories when necessary. Of course this can easily be taken too far by adding tens or hundreds of helper methods onto classes. If you go to far up into the chain, this could even have unintended consequences. As always, it's a much easier to defend choice if you practice writing well thought out comments for any potentially troubling code. As an aside, Xcode makes it a breeze to find the declaration of methods using Command + Click.

Answer (score 1):

UIButton's can reconfigure their titles for any of the UIControlState's (see here: [UIControlState](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState)).

Since using the dot syntax doesn't set the title for any specific state, the UIButton is likely re-configuring the title for UIControlStateNormal, which is set to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
myButton.titleLabel.text=@"foo";
```

here works

[]'s